# How do you disable / turn off Azure App Hosting plan (to avoid being charged)

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

It is possible to delete azure app hosting plan to stop being charged, but I am wondering if it's possible to disable it somehow. If you delete it, then you lose configuration, etc. But I did not find any options to kind of turn it off, and then put it back online (I suppose it's possible with virtual machines e.g.), or reduce the instance count to 0 somehow. Did someone find a way to do it?

P.S. Sometimes it's possible to switch to free plan, but e.g. it won't work when you have deployment slots, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to 'turn off' an Azure App Hosting Plan is to delete it! While it is up and running you will be charged.

The best solution you've got is to shrink it down to a single small server. The price for that is reasonably low.

The alternative is to automate the whole thing, If you keep the sites you host in Github etc you can create a hosting plan and deploy deployment slots etc from a script. You can host the scripts in Azure Automation, and it becomes a few minutes to redeploy your site. Although this does take a little time to create.